# Outlook 365 Cached Mode - Need Clarification

Tags: outlook, office365

I have a query regarding outlook 365 cached mode.  Say for example a new user has a outlook mails on server for three months say JAN, FEB and MAR.  Let's say we are in 1st of April, iam configuring outlook365 cached mode to 1 month.  So March mails will be available offline.  Let's say one month is passed, now we are in MAY.  Now what happens to MAR month mail which is already downloaded offline, since cache is set to one month.  Will MARCH and APRIL mails will be available offline, or only APRIL mails will be available and march gets removed locally?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if Cached Exchange Mode is enabled, Outlook caches email messages only from the last N months (in your case - 1-month-old) and removes anything older from the local cache for the PC. These default settings depend on the device, with mobile devices having smaller default settings. The email messages that are removed from the local cache are still available for users to view, but they’ll need to be connected to Exchange Server to view them. Users can view messages that were removed from the local cache by scrolling to the end of a message list in a folder and clicking the message Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange. Users can also change how much email to keep offline. The administrator can change the default age or enforce the age of email messages that are removed from the local cache.